# Laravel Passport - Change default Unauthenticated response to custom one

Tags: laravel, api, response, laravel-passport

Thank you in advance,

I am using laravel passport for API user authentication while if `access_token` is invalid then we are receiving response like below

```
{ 
    "message": "Unauthenticated." 
}
```

but I want that response like below

```
{ 
    "code" : 0,
    "message": "Unauthenticated." 
    "data" : [],
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to change how Laravel renders an error you can do it in your `app/Exceptions/Handler.php` class.

In this particular case you can override the `unauthenticated` method by adding te following to your `Handler` class:

```
protected function unauthenticated($request, AuthenticationException $exception)
{
    if ($request->expectsJson()) {
        return response()->json([
            'message' => $exception->getMessage(),
            'code'    => 0,
            'data'    => [],
        ], 401);
    }

    return redirect()->guest($exception->redirectTo() ?? route('login'));
}
```

Comment: Okay, thanks/ this will create any other issue or this exception method will only call when there is access token is wrong?
Or is there any other passport method to do the same thing? if any

Comment: @RonakSolanki This will fire whenever the unauthenticated exception is thrown e.g. whenever an unauthenticated user tries to access a protected route.

Comment: @RonakSolanki Did this answer you're question or are you still having issues with changing the Unauthenticated response?

Comment: Hello, sorry for the delay, yes i have used some of the logic from your answer. thank you

Comment: @RonakSolanki Glad I could help! :)